# What is actually being saved in the file when you save a model? For example a Tensorflow SavedModel file

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, pytorch, models, weights

I'm building a feature for my application that requires **reading the properties of a saved ML model file** (after it's trained). However, as I am pretty new to this field, I don't really understand the foundational knowledge about developing AI, only knowing that parameters are trained and saved. I have some experience with the Tensorflow framework, and I know that a model can be saved in either a `Savedmodel` file or a `h5` file.

My questions are:

1. What is actually being saved in those files typically? And what does it look like?
2. Is it a big difference when you save your model differently? for example `h5` vs `savedmodel` or tensorflow vs pytorch.
3. Is it possible for me to read meaningful information from any saved files regardless of the format? *So it doesn't matter if someone else used Pytorch, Tensorflow, or C to do ML*

Comment: Your questions seem to be off-topic here. They are mostly programming questions and specific to frameworks. We focus on the theoretical/non-programming aspects of AI.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to Question 1**

TensorFlow's [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/saving/save_model#:%7E:text=With%20save_format%3D%22tf%22%20%2C,are%20included%20in%20the%20SavedModel.) provides the following information on what is saved:

> The model config, weights, and optimizer are included in the SavedModel. Additionally, for every Keras layer attached to the model, the SavedModel stores:
>
> - The config and metadata -- e.g. name, dtype, trainable status
> - Traced call and loss functions, which are stored as TensorFlow subgraphs.

You can use [TensorBoard's Graphs dashboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs#:%7E:text=TensorBoard%27s%20Graphs%20dashboard%20is%20a,how%20TensorFlow%20understands%20your%20program.) to visualize your model.

For a quick dive watch [Tensorboard with Tensorflow 2.0 under 10 mins](https://youtu.be/Uzkhn5ENJzQ?t=434).

**Answer to Question 2**

See jdehesa's answer to a similar question regarding TF and H5 files: [What is the difference between .pb SavedModel and .tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006270/what-is-the-difference-between-pb-savedmodel-and-tf-savedmodel)

**Answer to Question 3**

Yes. Both formats, .pb and .tf, are used to save meaningful data and are used for reading in the models.

Comment: so based on your answer, is it true that most ML models are saved in a similar architecture that contains model config, weights, and optimizer? Or I think what I really want to ask is, how do I read information from ML model files of any format, regardless if it was trained with Tensorflow or Pytorch.